# Finding the location of point P

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle, triangulation

Is it possible to find the location of point $P$ such that the angles $\theta_1=\theta_2$ or $\alpha_1=\alpha_2$?
I know only the locations of $O$, $C_1$, and $C_2$.

[image: Location of Point P]

Comment: Is $\theta_1$ given? Otherwise point $P$ is not unique.

Comment: No, it's not. The only information I have is the location of $O$, $C_1$, and $C_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a coordinate system, consider $P=(a,b)$ and find the equation of the line $\overline{OP}$. The point $S$ of intersection of lines $\overline{OP}$ and $\overline{C_1C_2}$ is computible. 
Finally note that $PS$ is the bisector of angle $C_1PC_2$, thus we have
$$\frac{PC_1}{PC_2}=\frac{C_1S}{SC_2}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't know how to compute point $S$.

Comment: The point $S$ is intersection of two lines $\overline{OP}$ and $\overline{C_1C_2}$. This intersection can be find by solving a system of linear equations (i.e. that of $\overline{OP}$ and $\overline{C_1C_2}$) in terms of $a$ and $b$

Answer (score 3):

Here's a geometric construction for $P$. On $OC_1$ as base construct an isosceles triangle $OBC_1$ such that $\angle BC_1O=\angle BOC_1=\alpha-90°$. All points of the circle arc of center $B$ and passing through $O$ make with $OC_1$ an angle $\alpha$. Construct in the same way another isosceles triangle $OAC_2$ and an arc $OC_2$: point $P$ lies then at the intersection of those two arcs.

[image]

EDIT.

If the triangle is right-angled at $O$ it is quite easy to find the equation of the locus of point $P$. In that case we can choose the coordinates of the vertices as
$$
O=(0,0),\quad C_1=(a,0),\quad C_2=(0,b)
$$
and the coordinates of the circle centers as
$$
A=(a/2,-ta/2),\quad B=(-tb/2,b/2),
$$
where $t$ is a real parameter. The coordinates of $P$ turn out to be:
$$
P=\left(
{ab(1-t^2)(at+b)\over(at+b)^2+(bt+a)^2},
{ab(1-t^2)(bt+a)\over(at+b)^2+(bt+a)^2}
\right)
$$
and they thus define a parametric curve (shown in diagram below). One can also eliminate $t$ to find the implicit equation of the curve:
$$
(x^2+y^2)(ay-bx)=ab(y^2-x^2).
$$

[image]

Notice that only the points on the blue and red arcs of the curve satisfy the request $\angle C_1PO=\angle C_2PO$, while the points on the dashed arcs don't. The blue and red arcs are then the required locus.

Comment: How to construct $\alpha-90^\circ$? The angle $\alpha$ depends on location of $P$, isn't it?

Comment: As I wrote in my comment above, if angles $\theta$ and $\alpha$ are not known then many different solutions for $P$ are possible. In other words: for every value of $\alpha>90°$ the above construction will give you a possible location of $P$.

Comment: Isn't possibly the question asking to find the LOCUS of point $P$? That would make more sense.

Comment: Let me be more precise: point $P$ exists for $0<\alpha<\angle OC_1C_2$ and $\angle OC_2C_1<\alpha<180°-{1\over2}\angle C_1OC_2$.