# A curve with $\angle APB =\angle APC$

Tags: geometry

In $\triangle ABC$, define $\{P\mid\angle APB=\angle APC\}$.

I have known that it is not a curve with degree 2, i.e. conic section. Then, what is its degree?

And may I ask is there a name for this? Moreover, is there a formula?

Thank you.

Here’s a possible way to construct:
Draw a hyperbola passes through $A,B,C,H,A’$, where $H$ is the orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$ and $A’$ is the antipode of $A$ wrt circle $(ABC)$; next, invert the hyperbola with circle $(A,\sqrt{AB*AC})$, i.e. a circle centered at $A$ with radius of $\sqrt{AB*AC}$. Lastly, reflect the inverted curve with the angle bisector of $\angle BAC$. Here’s a picture drawn with GeoGebra for reference.[image]

Comment: The curve is a cubic, here's its equation if angle $A$ is right: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2693865/finding-the-location-of-point-p/2694366#2694366

Comment: The curve is described on page 333 of Eagles' book "Constructive geometry of curves", [Problem 167](https://archive.org/details/constructivegeom00eagluoft/page/333/mode/1up).